# ruby on rails: stars specified by js are not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Currently I am doing displaying star_rate as below, but, after all, posts from the second star_rate and beyond are not displayed.
Why is this?
please tell me!

```
<% @listings.each do |listing| %>
  <div class="card w-75">
    <div class="card-block">
      <div id="average_star_rate"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <script>
    $('#average_star_rate').raty({
      path: '/assets',
      readOnly: true,
      score: <%= listing.average_star_rate %>
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I haven no idea how to reproduce your problem, given the limited information provided. What is `@listings`? What is the `raty` JS method? What is `Listing#average_star_rate`? What do you mean by "the second `star_rate` and beyond"? What is the expected/desired behaviour, and what are you seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code.

First of all, there can only be one element with a given `id` on a page. Here you are creating many in the loop.

Second, what you are trying to do with the selector is problematic. You are asking it to select *all matching elements*, but what you really want to select is only the *current element of that iteration*.

The first problem is easy to resolve. You just change `id="average_star_rate"` to `class="average_star_rate"`, and lookup `.average_star_rate` instead of `#average_star_rate`

The second is not quite so trivial but isn't difficult either. One way to do it is to make a tracker attribute which can be used for lookup. You can add this to the div:

```
data-id='<%= listing.id %>'
```

and then change the query to as follows:

```
$(".average_star_rate[data-id='<%= listing.id %>']").raty({
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.
It was very easy to understand and, as it was, it was displayed well.
That was a really big help. Thank you very much.